# Reformulate max function into linear program using constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have the following objective function

```
minimize 1000 + 3*max(0, x-10)
```

How do I reformulate this into a linear program?

Answer (score 2):

Introduce new variable `y`:

Post:

```
y >= 0
y >= x-10
```

Adapt Objective:

```
minimize 1000 + 3 * y
```